# Usar variables fuera de un método en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente fragmento de código:

```
def input():
    global e
    string = e.get()
    print ("Hola "+string)
```

Quiero usar la variable `string` fuera del método, para crear otro método nuevo o para cualquier otra cosa. ¿Cómo podría sacar el valor de la variable fuera del método?

Gracias.

Comment: Pues depende de cómo quieras usarlo. Podrías usar `return string`, con lo cual podrías *recoger* el valor con `s = input()` en otra parte, o podrías declarar `string` *fuera* del método y simplemente usarlo ahí con `global` igual que estás haciendo con la `e`

Answer (score 2):

Vamos a empezar por aclarar que las variables globales, a no ser que no tengas ningún otro recurso para evitarlas, son siempre indeseables, y hay [muchas razones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad) por lo cual esto es cierto.

Entonces ¿qué podemos hacer para evitarlas? Pues intentar acercarnos, en lo sumo posible, a construir [funciones puras](https://stackabuse.com/functional-programming-in-python/). Es decir, funciones que no tengan efectos secundarios y que no produzcan output arguments, ya que, como el buen Robert Martin (2008, p. 45) explica:

> En general, los argumentos de salida [output arguments] deberían ser evitados. Si tu función debe cambiar del estado de algo, que sea el estado del objeto que la posee.

Teniendo esto claro, veamos tu situación: Estás usando una variable global (`e`), la cual usas para producir un valor (`string`) que quieres usar en otra parte.

Como yo lo veo, tienes todo para construir una función pura en la cual su entrada sea `e`, su proceso sea la obtención de `string`, y esta última sea precisamente su salida. Incluso, con un poco de contexto, podemos darle un nombre a la función que nos permita identificar claramente qué hace (y, por supuesto, evitar usar un nombre ya usado por la builtin function `input()`, lo cual siempre debe ser evitado, como bien explicó ArianJM).

Podemos hacer, entonces:

```
def obtener_string_a_partir_de(e):
    string = e.get()
    return string
```

Ahora bien, por lo visto quieres imprimir la variable `string`. Como también debemos tener en cuenta que, como el mismo Martin explica, las funciones deben hacer una sola cosa, podemos crear otra función que se encargue de imprimir `string`.

```
def imprimir(string):
    print("Hola " + string)
```

Agrupando ambas partes:

```
string = obtener_string_a_partir_de(e)
imprimir(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo suyo sería devolverlo como resultado de la función:

```py
def mi_funcion():
    global e
    string = e.get()
    print("Hola " + string)

    return string

string_fuera = mi_funcion()
print("Hola fuera " + string_fuera)
```

Te recomiendo que no crees una función `input()` porque esa [ya existe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) y la estarás machacando. Luego si quieres usar el `input()` original puede ser confuso.